# stuck while learning bit banging

Tags: bit, microchip

This is my first question as I am new to coding.

Well, I am trying to use a MCP digipot in SPI. As I am using a PIC16, writing in C, I learned that the XC8 library couldn't be included in a PIC16 project... So I thought I would learn a lot doing it by bit banging, understanding what I do...

But...Doesn't seem to work ! So I have made a LED version with some delay in order to see what was happening.

I have two problems: First, the "command" data doesn't seem to be shifted. I can only see a flash for the first bit then it turns out. The "clock" led works fine, flashing 8 times.

Also, I don't understand why my infinite loop isn't infinite. I get a few cycles then the main function is called back and so on. It has something to do with my delays as it changes the number of cycles when I change the delay.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pic16f18875.h>

#define temoin LATAbits.LATA0
#define CS LATAbits.LATA1
#define CLK LATAbits.LATA2
#define DAT LATAbits.LATA3

#define MASK = 0x80 //isolate the MSB

unsigned char commande = 0b10011000; //led sequence to be observed (command)

void delay(void)
    {              int f, g;
                    for(f=0;f<1000;f++)
            {
                      for(g=0;g<1;g++)
                  {  } } }     //simple delay                    

void main()
{
        int i;

//init                        
        TRISA=0x00;    //porta as output
        LATA = 0x00; //init all bits to 0        

        CS=0;   //enable writing               

 //send command

        for (i=0; i<8; i++) //browse through the command byte
            {

            if (commande & MASK) //read msb and compare                      
                     DAT = 1;                        
            else                        
                     DAT = 0;


                CLK=1; //clock signal
                delay();                   
                CLK=0;
                delay();

              commande <<=1; //left shift, read next bit 

            }

        CS = 1;

        while (1) //just a heartbeat
        {
          temoin = 1;
          delay();             
          temoin = 0;
          delay();             
        }
}
```

I have really tried a lot to find any info on the web but none worked fine for me. I might just lack a special C language knowledge, but I couldn't tell what.

Thanks in advance !

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your problem is simply that your `#define` is messed up:

```
#define MASK = 0x80 //isolate the MSB
             ^- ???
```

That equal sign ends up getting treated as part of the definition, so the preprocessor will expand

```
if (commande & MASK) //read msb and compare
```

to:

```
if (commande & = 0x80) //read msb and compare
```

which isn't what you wanted at all! This ends up modifying `commande` in the `if` statement, masking out all of the bits lower than `0x80`.

Removing the `=` in the definition should fix this.

---

With regard to the other part -- the infinite loop not being infinite -- make sure that your processor doesn't have a watchdog timer enabled. You may need to disable it in fuse bits.

Comment: Thanks so much guys !
It worked fine for both ideas, perfect.